# Unit test the code which is in Task.Run() in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have to write unit test to verify the code which was run by Task.Run(),which is wrapped inside an async action as shown below.Since I am not awaiting for the task to complete I am not able to achieve this as Task.Run() runs separately.

The requirement is that The call  `this.KeepAlive(accountNumber, token)` should not be waited to complete to call the next statement.But if that KeepAlive service call fails or any validation fails then it should be  logged.

```
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        readonly IService service;
        readonly IService2 service2;

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IService service, IService2 service2)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.service = service;
            this.service2 = service2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<bool> Testmethod(string accountNumber, string viewName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            _ = Task.Run(() => this.KeepAlive(accountNumber, token));

            var accountStatus = await this.service2.GetValidName(viewName, token);
            return accountStatus=="Myname";
        }

        private async Task KeepAlive(string name, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                _logger.LogError("name is empty or null");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                var isAlive = await this.service.ChekStatusAsyc(name, token);
                if (!isAlive)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Unable to process the request");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                _logger.LogError("Service ChekStatusAsyc Failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to verify below in my unit tests

1. whether service was called
2. validation logging happened
3. Exception logging

The Test which was written as below will not work, since I am not awaiting for task to complete.

```
[Fact]
        public async void KeepAliveAsyncShouldBeCalledErrorShouldBeLoggedIfServiceFails()
        {
            var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<WeatherForecastController>>();
            var mockservice = new Mock<service>();
            mockservice.Setup(x => x.ChekStatusAsyc(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(false);
            var mockservice2 = new Mock<service2>();
            var controller = new WeatherForecastController(mockLogger.Object, mockservice.Object, mockservice2.Object);

            var result = await controller.Testmethod("account0", "test");

            mockservice.Verify(x => x.ChekStatusAsyc(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
        }
```

As I am not awaiting, I can't verify anything which was run by Task.Run().

If I use 
`await this.KeepAlive(accountNumber, token)` then the test case which I wrote will work as expected,but it will wait for the task to complete.which is not as per the requirement.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I would write 2 tests, one for the original spec and another to test the KeepAlive task. You should be able to assert that the task is in a status of running before your original test method closes.Still, that would be another test in keeping with Single Responsibility.

Comment: I am happy to write it,How can I alter the current test? which just verifies the service call?

Comment: The way I would do it is to refactor the KeepAlive method out to another class, and make the method public. Then use an instance of that new class to provide you with the method. That way you could test the KeepAlive with it's own set of tests, and you wouldn't have to worry about testing it in your TestMethod above. All you would need to check is that it was called, the rest would be covered by other passing tests.

Comment: @Muralikrishna Put Keep alive in a hosted service (since it appears you are using asp.net-core). Right now the shown code violates SRP. The discovered problem in the unit test only exposes the code smell.

Comment: Completely Agreed the logic in KeepAlive method can be tested separately. But If I move it to separate class,I need to verify whether the new class is being called in the current controller actoin. Which boils down to the same problem where I need to verify whether stubbed method of the interface is being called. @NikP

Comment: @Nkosi The ```this.service.ChekStatusAsyc(name, token);``` already separated,here only I am receiving the response and logging  accordingly,As mentioned if I move this logic to separate class/interface,then I need to mock and verify that whether that new method is being called,which is equal to same problem , which I am facing.

Comment: For this particular test, await a `Task.Delay` after calling the SUT and then perform your validation.

Comment: I believe you are missing my point about using a hosted service but I guess that is outside of the scope of your current problem.

Comment: @Nkosi,As Task.Run() taken care by OS,Adding the delay in some cases it might work,but I don't think it will be correct?Any other suggestion ca think of?

Comment: Right now your controller has an instance of ```IService``` passed into it. If it's only being used in the ```KeepAlive``` method, split KeepAlive out to a new class and inject the service into that class instead. If ```service``` is also being used somewhere else in the controller that we can't see, pass ```service``` into the new KeepAlive class method as a parameter. Either way you will decouple your code and you can test it.

Comment: @NikP absolutely correct. I did refactor and moved the logging mechanism to the method 'ChekStatusAsyc' My only problem is the code fails some times as it will run is=n separate task. I am not intended to use delay to overcome the problem.```mockservice.Verify(x => x.ChekStatusAsyc(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);```